# Is there a file path behaviour fixup

Tags: input

I have the following structure:

In main file

```
\input{figs/figure.tex_t}
```

In `figs/figure.tex_t`:

```
\includegraphics{figure.pdf}
```

This results in build failure, since `\input` does not affect the current search path. Is it possible to achieve the C preprocessor behavior so `pdflatex` starts looking in the same directory as the currently processed file?

I should mention that `figure.tex_t` is autogenerated, so it is not a solution to modify this file.

## Edit:

I found the `\import` package but it does not seem to help:

```
\subimport{figs}{figure.tex_t}
```

Give me error:

> (figs/figure.tex_t
>
> ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `figure.pdf' not found.

Comment: just put figs in the search path either with `\graphicspath{{figs/}}` within the document or set `TEXINPUTS=figs:` in the environment before starting latex

Comment: DavidCarlisle: This is not a real solution though.

Comment: It depends how you define real. It is the way that tex in general and the graphics package in particular are designed to be used.

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=docotherdir. You could also try the currfile package to retrieve pathes at runtime.